# What is Memoryanalyzer.dll

Tags: internet-explorer, dll

I am wondering the use of Memoryanalyzer.dll in Internet Explorer.

I have two version of internet Explorer 11 in two PC.

1.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3032359

2.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3175443

But there is a **Memoryanalyzer.dll** file listed in to the list.

In the first version **KB3175443**

[image]

In the Second Version **KB3175443** is display as a Not Applicable

[image]
So, My question is why Memoryanalyzer.dll is not applicable in new version ?

Comment: It applies to the Platform column, you are looking at the update for ARM processors for some reason.  Which doesn't distinguish between different kinds of ARM processors so it is not applicable.  Doesn't have anything to do with whether or not the DLL is used.  It is.

Comment: I am suffering memory leak related problem.
The first IE is not create the problem but second IE is creating.
i supposed may be Memoryanalyzer.dll is responsible for it.